# Circles do not display properly in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

I need to draw a slanted ovals in IE8.

To display a border-radius is used PIE.js

To display in other browsers use the code:

```
.levelConfidenceCircleBlue {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 19px;
    height: 18px;
    background: none;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.levelConfidenceCircleBlue:before,
.levelConfidenceCircleBlue:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";

    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #00A7E7;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px/63px;
    border-radius: 50px/63px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(26deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(26deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(26deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(26deg);
            transform: rotate(26deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

To adjust for the use IE8 hack:

```
<! - [if IE 8]>
.levelConfidenceCircleBlue:before,
.levelConfidenceCircleBlue:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";

    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 0px;

    background: none;
    border-radius: 60px 40px 60px 40px;
    -pie-background: #00A7E7;
}
<! [endif] ->
```

did not change. However, if you change it to:

```
<! - [if IE 8]>    
.levelConfidenceCircleBlue {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 19px;
        height: 18px;
        background: none;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-top: -8px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .levelConfidenceCircleBlue:before,
    .levelConfidenceCircleBlue:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";

        width: 15px;
        height: 18px;
        left: 0px;

        background: none;
        border-radius: 60px 40px 60px 40px;
        -pie-background: #00A7E7;
    }
<! [endif] ->
```

it shows up correctly in IE8 in IE9 - displays the squares, in other browsers - nothing is displayed.
addition to regular classes without the   hacks / *** / and \ 0 / does not work.

Can you please tell how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
The problem was connected PIE.js.

Connection is changed to:

```
updatePIEButtons = function () {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {


        $(".levelConfidenceCircleBlue").each(function () {
                PIE.detach(this);
                PIE.attach(this);
            });
        }
        else {
            $("[other classes]").each(function () {
                PIE.detach(this);
                PIE.attach(this);
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional tag for IE seems wrong.

```
<!--[if IE 8]> IE 8.0 <![endif]-->
```